# Why my Selenium web driver is not clicking on Element identified by id?

Tags: selenium, drop-down-menu, automation, treenode

My Selenium web driver is not clicking on this tree node. I don't know exactly what we say it tree node or something else so this is image and I highlighted the element.

[image]

This right arrow part on which I want to click

And this is my code:

```
//wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("iconDiv"))); 
WebElement taskdropElementid = driver.findElement(By.id("iconDiv"));
System.out.println(taskdropElementid.getAttribute("class"));
if(taskdropElementid.getAttribute("class").equals("RightArrow")) 
  taskdropElementid.click();
```

Printing statement is giving me output dropdown. I think it should give RightArrow and when I am uncommenting wait part then it is continuously wait for the element to be clickable.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Printing statement is giving me output dropdown

That means there are multiple elements with the same id `iconDiv` and unfortunately you're locating other element instead which has class name `dropdown`.

If you want to locate element with class name `RightArrow`, You should try using `By.cssSelector()` to locate it uniquely as below :-

```
WebElement taskdropElementid = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#iconDiv.RightArrow"));
taskdropElementid.click();
```

Comment: @kamal kumar You should [mark this answer as correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped...:)